# How to look for uniques in other column relatively assign ids

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a toy example to explain what I am trying to work on :

`aski = data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","a","d","d"),y=c("b","a","d","a","b","c"))`

I managed to do assigning unique ids to column y and now output looks like:

`aski2 = data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","a","d","d"),y=c("1","2","3","2","1","4"))`

as you see "b" is present in both col x and y and we assigned an id=1 in col y
and "a" with id=2 in col y and so on..
As you see these values are also present in col x.....
col x has "a" as its first element ."a" was also in col y and assigned an id=2
so I'll assign an id=2 for a in col x also
Now what i m trying to do next is look for these values in col x and if it occurs in col y I assign that id to it

**FINAL DATAFRAME LIKE**

`aski3 = data.frame(x=c("2","1","4","2","3","3"),y=c("1","2","3","2","1","4"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert both columns to character vectors.
Then, collect all unique values from the two columns to use as levels of a factor.

Convert both columns to factors, then numeric.

```
aski = data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","a","d","d"),y=c("b","a","d","a","b","c"))

aski$x <- as.character(aski$x)
aski$y <- as.character(aski$y)

lev <- unique(c(aski$y, aski$x))
aski$x <- factor(aski$x, levels=lev)
aski$y <- factor(aski$y, levels=lev)

aski$x <- as.numeric(aski$x)
aski$y <- as.numeric(aski$y)
aski
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the need to create `aski2` as an intermediate, a possible solution is to use `match` with `lapply` to get the numeric representations of the letters:

```
# create a vector of the unique values in the order
# in which you want them assigned to '1' till '4'
v <- unique(aski$y) 

# convert both columns to integer values with 'match' and 'lapply'
aski[] <- lapply(aski, match, v)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > aski
>   x y
> 1 2 1
> 2 1 2
> 3 4 3
> 4 2 2
> 5 3 1
> 6 3 4
> ```

If you want the number as characters, you can additionally do:

```
aski[] <- lapply(aski, as.character)
```

Comment: Great answer. Here is a way to automatically create `v`: `v <-
 unique(aski$y)`, at least it looks like what the OP wants.

Comment: @ycw I know; something like that was in my initial answer; can't remember why I didn't include it in my final answer :-/

Answer (score 1):

A solution from `dplyr`. We can first create a vector showing the relationship between index and letter as `vec` by `unique(aski$y)`. After this step, you can use Jaap's `lapply` solution, or you can use `mutata_all` from `dplyr` as follows.

```
# Create the vector showing the relationship of index and letter 
vec <- unique(aski$y)
# View vec
vec
[1] "b" "a" "d" "c"

library(dplyr)

# Modify all columns
aski2 <- aski %>% mutate_all(funs(match(., vec)))
# View the results
aski2
  x y
1 2 1
2 1 2
3 4 3
4 2 2
5 3 1
6 3 4
```

**Data**

```
aski <- data.frame(x = c("a","b","c","a","d","d"),
                   y = c("b","a","d","a","b","c"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```